# Jar no se ejecuta

Tags: java

Ahora tengo otro problema cuando hago mi JAR se abre una pantalla negra y se cierra

¿A qué se debe?

Me aparece esto:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at seiem.Login.<init>(Login.java:24)
        at seiem.Login$3.run(Login.java:181)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionP
rivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

CLASE LOGIN:

```
package seiem;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public static final String URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CEDULA";
    public static final String Usuario="root";
    public static final String Contraseña="12345678";

    public Login() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);

        setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Seiem/logo.png")).getImage());
        ((JPanel)getContentPane()).setOpaque(false);
        ImageIcon MyImgCustom=new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/Seiem/seiem.jpg"));
        JLabel fondo=new JLabel();

        fondo.setIcon(MyImgCustom);
        getLayeredPane().add(fondo,JLayeredPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER);
        fondo.setBounds(0,0,MyImgCustom.getIconWidth(),MyImgCustom.getIconHeight());
    }
private void IngresarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Connection con=null;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(URL, Usuario, Contraseña);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bienvenido al sistema");
            CedulaIdentificacion abrir=new CedulaIdentificacion();
            abrir.setVisible(true);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }       
    }               
private void CancelarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        System.exit(0);
    }
 public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Login().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: deberias abrirlo x consola y ver que errores te genera algo asi:... java -jar "archivo.jar"

Answer (score 0):

Sencillo. Tú código, clase Login, tiene un NullPointerException

```
seiem.Login$3.run(Login.java:181)
```

Esto pasa al momento de ejecutarse con los datos que tiene a mano. Ya si quieres saber por qué, habría que examinar el código.

Comment: ¿Como puedo subir mi programa aquí soy usuario nuevo?

Comment: Editas tu pregunta y pegas allí el fragmento del código en la clase Login que crees que es relevante para tu problema.

Comment: Truena en la linea 24 de Login.java al parecer no encuentra una imagen.La ruta cambia cuando ejecutas desde un IDE a cuando ejecutas desde un jar.

Comment: Ya esta solucionado. Gracias a todos!!

Comment: @FidelÁngelPérez si publicas la solución, le puede servir a los que puedan tener un problema similar